# How to show a small image to the right of a div with CSS?

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a div formatted like the following:

```
Loading XYZ Data .... [loading image]
```

Then later when the data has been loaded, then I want to switch the css class to something else, and result in:

```
Loading XYZ Data .... [green checkbox image]
```

How can this be done? Currently I'm doing this:

```
.loading
{
    background-image: url(images/loading.gif);
    background-position: 100% right;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

However the image doesn't show up next to the next where I want it to. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
span.bg_square
{
    display: block;
    background-image: url(http://www.vesivus.com/minis/little_square.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
    padding-right: 20px;
    width: 70px;
}
```

[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/nv5yQ/).

Comment: This is working however there's a bit of gap between where the text stops and image begins, e.g `Loading...      [image]` instead of `Loading...[image]`. Any ideas?

Comment: May be its because I'm not using width? I want to use the class in different places where widths would be different.

Answer (score 1):

`background-position: 100% right` doesn't make it go 100% to the right, if that's what you're thinking. If you want to use background images, you'd be better off to add a `padding-right`to the `.loading` div, with a value of however many pixels wide your loading gif is. Then use `background-position: right top`. You don't need `background-attachment` either.